# How to query the Canvas using Selenium and Javascript executor?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, canvas, automation, protractor

I like to know if its possible to automate this 'graph' which is created on the canvas, if yes, how  to automate it. I have to interact with all the elements on the 'graph or a map like thing' by clicking on an element and dragging the elements and performing other actions like getting the text, etc. 
Is this possible in automation using selenium with JavaScript executor, can anyone help.
 i already scour the internet, but didn't find anything useful or which even remotely answer the question i have. if any one can help, please do write an answer. i cannot share the real picture due to security reasons, but this is almost the same not identical.[image: see the image below]

Comment: You should consider posting this also on [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=canvas) exchange

Comment: Okay,ill post it there thanks after 40 minutes.

Comment: If the CANVAS app has an API available, you can use JSE to send commands. Is this a page/app that you or the company you work for owns?

Comment: This is an interactive app, all elements on this page do something when you click or drag them.

Comment: @JeffC this is actually a web page not just an app, i also have a sidebar when i interact with any element on the canvas sidebar will reflect those changes.

Comment: Right but a CANVAS tag acts like an app inside the HTML page. I've worked with them before but you have to have access to the API to be able to interact with them and only using JS.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate

this is what you need. But you need to know variable names (internal logic of the canvas) in order to retrieve data